# Set of indices of well-defined series is in turn well-defined.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the following set $S$ well-defined?

$$ \phi = \left\{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} | \sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} \in \mathbb{R} \right\}. $$

My guess would be that it is, as the fact that impossibility to determine the convergence of any particular series does not imply that the limit exists (or not), thus, the belonging of any $A_1$ to $\phi$ can be defined.

There is no particular background on this question. I was just reflecting on convergence. In fact, I was wondering about a more general question, which I'll state below.

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \leftarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative function. Positivity is imposed to avoid convergence issues.

Define $\phi_f$ as

$$ \phi_f = \left\{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} | \sum_{a \in A} f(a) \in \mathbb{R} \right\}. $$

Is it possible to characterize the equivalence class of functions such that $f_1 \sim f_2$ iff $\phi_{f_1} = \phi_{f_2}$.

Perhaps, additional restrictions should be imposed on $f$, beyond non-negativity, to ease a characterization.

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be well-defined?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \text{Let}\  S= \left\{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} | \sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} \in \mathbb{R} \right\} $$
Yes $S$ is  well defined because you can figer out whether a subset of $\mathbb N$ is in $S$ or not. For example

Take $A= \mathbb N$ then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty \notin \mathbb R$ so $A=\mathbb N \notin S$

Now take $A=\{1,2,3\}$ then $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \in \mathbb R$ so $A \in S$

Pick a subset $A$ of $\mathbb N$ and compute whether sum of reciprocals of elements of $A$ is finite or infinte. There is no ambiguity whether $A$ will lie in $S$ or not because if sum is infinite then $A \notin S$ and if sum is finite then $A \in S$.

Comment: I think you will find that it isn't always "easily" figured out. But the difficulty of such a proof is more or less irrelevant. What is relevant is whether membership in $S$ is ambiguous, not whether it is provable. (Which might or might not be the same thing. But that's probably not a discussion for this time.)

Comment: Edited : we can not say that if $A$ is infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ then $A \notin S$

Comment: Pick a subset and try whether it is in $S$ or not. There is no ambiguity here. So this set is well defined